# Proving $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^2}{x+1}=-\infty$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I have not been able to find any examples for this, so I'm unsure about my presentation (or answer for that matter). If anyone could also provide a link to a list of examples that I could work through, that would be very much appreciated.

**Question:**

Use the precise definition to prove:-

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^2}{x+1}=-\infty$$

**Attempted answer**:

For every number $N < 0$ there is some number $M < 0$ such that:

-->   $- f(x) < N$ whenever $-x < M$

-->   $-|\frac{x^2}{x+1}|< N$

-->   $-|{x}| < -|\frac{x^2}{x+1}| < N$

-->   $-|x| < N$

-->   Let M = N, then $-x < M$ implies that $-f(x) < N$

This is all over the place. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are many mistakes in your attempt. You need $f(x)<n$ whenever $x <M$ not  $-f(x)<n$ whenever $-x <M$. Absolute value signs are making this confusing.

Answer (score 1):

We may suppose $N <-2$. You want $\frac {x^{2}} {x+1} <N$. This is same as $x^{2} >N(x+1)$ (when $x+1 <0$). Write this as $(x-\frac N 2)^{2}>N+\frac {N^{2}} 2$. This in equality holds if $x <\frac N 2 - \sqrt { N+\frac {N^{2}} 2}$. So take $M=\frac N 2 - \sqrt { N+\frac {N^{2}} 2}$. This gives $f(x) <N$ whenever $x <M$.

Comment: That choice of $M$ doesn't work when $-2<N<0$.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the comment. I have added the assumption $N<-2$ to my proof.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly is all over the place, but that's nothing surprising for a novice in the field. Writing mathematical proofs is not easy, and it takes skill, patience and practice.

What you wrote is the process one should take when trying to prove a statement, but 1) it is wrong, because $-|x|<\left|\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right|$ is **false** for $x=10$, for example, and 2) you are missing one final part of that, and that is, once you see where you are, you need to actually *write the proof*.

That is, once you discover what $M$ should be, then take that $N$ and write the proof in the following form:

> Let $N>0$. Then, take $M=...$ and let $x < M$. Then, $\dots$, and therefore, $\frac{x^2}{x+1} < N$.

where of course, you fill in the places where "$\dots$" is written